# Fancybox Buttons not showing when opening in parent page

Tags: jquery, html, fancybox

Ok I had asked a question before about how to open fancybox from an iframe to the parent page.  And the solution worked like a charm and still works.  Now I've been asked for it to show the left, right arrows but it seems that the code to open in parent page causes it not to show the buttons? :S  here's what I have so far:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.fancybox-buttons.css?v=2.0.3" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.fancybox-buttons.js?v=2.0.3"></script>

 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.css?v=2.0.3" />
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.js?v=2.0.3"></script>
 <script>
     /* <![CDATA[ */
     $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.fancybox-buttons').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    parent.$.fancybox({
            openEffect  : 'none',
            closeEffect : 'none',

            prevEffect : 'none',
            nextEffect : 'none',

            closeBtn  : false,

            helpers : {
                title : {
                    type : 'inside'
                },
                buttons : {}
            },
            href: this.href
        });
    });
       }); // ready
       /* ]]> */
     </script>
```

if I change this:

```
$('.fancybox-buttons').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    parent.$.fancybox({
```

to

```
$('.fancybox-buttons').fancybox({
```

it works, except that it doesn't open in my parent page.  Help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you have loaded in both pages, the parent page and the iframed page, all jquery and fancybox css and js files (including the buttons and thumbs js and css files)?

On the other hand, you said that if you remove the `parent` reference then the code shows the left/right nav arrows? that would be weird since you are using the "manual" call method (to open in the parent page), where you cannot have the default galleries unless you set your galleries **manually** within your custom script like:

```
$('.fancybox-buttons').click(function(e){
 e.preventDefault();
 parent.$.fancybox([
  {href:'images/01.jpg', title: '01'},
  {href:'images/02.jpg', title: '02'},
  {href:'images/03.jpg', title: '03'}
 ],{
  // href: this.href // not needed
  // other options, e.g.
  helpers : {
   title : {
    type : 'inside'
    },
   buttons : {}
  },
  ......etc.
 }); // fancybox
}); // click
```

I updated my [demo page here](http://picssel.com/playground/jquery/fancyboxFromIframe_26Jan12.html) if you want to check it out.

Comment: quick question why are you setting the images inside jquery? can't it read from all the images that have "fancybox-buttons" as a class?

Comment: not with the manual method (using jQuery click()) ...if you use $('.fancybox-buttons').fancybox() then you could but you are using $('.fancybox-buttons').click() in order to open in parent page. As you can see the solution of the first issue brought you limitations in the second.

Comment: Ohhh got it thanks man works like a charm, luckily its only about 5 pictures so I don't have to write as much ;)

Answer (score 0):

You should initialize the `fanchbox` plguin on an element from parent window it will work.

```
$('someElementOrButtonFromParent', window.parent).fancybox();
```

Comment: not quite sure i understand this..my pictures are inside the iframe but when i show them using fancybox i wanted the popup to show in parent..that part works, what doesn't is the helper buttons like the next and back arrows and so on